# subjunctive mood without 'would'?

Tags: grammar, subjunctives

I've seen the sentence below in The TV show Friends.

*If little Joey's dead, then I got no reason to live.*

But I think it should be

*If little Joey's dead, then I would/should/might get no reason to live.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is ungrammatically spoken intentionally to show a regional accent or a poorly educated speaker. Your change is insufficient to make it correct, though you're going in the right direction. It could be corrected with "would have..."

*If little Joey's dead, then I would have no reason to live.*

Or, to be pedantic,

*If little Joey **were** to die, then I would have no reason to live.* [If he **is** already dead, why use the subjunctive?]